# asp.net mvc 2 forward request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

how can I forward request from controller to another url in the app that I have a route defined for?

Thanks

-- MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RedirectToRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505117.aspx) or [`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470154.aspx) should do the trick.